# How do I remove a specific string of text that has variables

Tags: wordpress, text, hide

I am using a wordpress site. I want to remove or replace some text.  This is content from a plugin I am unable to change the output (at least from all of my attempts to).

For example with the brackets;

(The Text: date1⁠–date2)

(The Text: Feb-09-Feb-12)

The two dates are variable, as in they will change all of the time.  Is there a way I can set a wildcard to say whatever is in data1 and data2 replace the string date1-date2 with X or remove that whole string "(The Text: date1⁠–date2)" altogether.

Is there a function I can add to my themes function.php file?

Or as an alternative using css. This text is within a div that I can set to disply:none but inside that I need another div to display.  My thinking was to just remove the text, as above.  Again this is content from a plugin I am unable to change the output (at least from all of my attempts to).  I tried visibility but it leaves the space where that text was.

How can I display something inside a div that is set to display:none?

So

```
<div style="display:none">
  <div>
    display something
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't display something inside an element set to `display: none;`. You could try and set the `font-size` of the element to 0, and use the `:after` selector to add your text to the `content` and set the `font-size` back to something readable:

```css
div { font-size: 0; }
div:after { font-size: 16px; content: "This Text is shown"; }
```

```html
<div>(The Text: date01-date02)</div>
```

Alternatively, it's a bit of a "hammer to hit a fly" solution, but using the [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect) hook, you can turn on [Output Buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) and run [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) on the content in the buffer, it's a technique I like to call "Runtime find & replace".

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'global_find_replace', 99 );
function global_find_replace(){
    ob_start( function( $buffer ){
        $text   = 'Your Text Here';
        $buffer = preg_replace('/\(The Text: .*\)/', $text, $buffer );

        return $buffer;
    });
}
```

---

#### Documentation & Function Reference

| Function | Linked Description |
| --- | --- |
| `template_redirect` | [Fires before determining which template to load.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect) |
| `preg_replace()` | [Perform a regular expression search and replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) |

Comment: Thanks I will give these a try and report back if it provides the result I am after.